# Unable to export query result from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to export query result in to CSV file from PHPMyAdmin

How to do that?

See the below picture. Normally I can see the option to check all, edit and delete rows.

[image]

But when I run this query

```
SELECT n.id
     , n.gazette_notice_id
     , n.notice_code
     , n.publication_date
     , n.company_number
     , c.company_name
     , c.registered_address_line_1
     , c.registered_address_line_2
     , c.registered_address_town
     , c.registered_address_county
     , c.registered_address_country
     , c.registered_address_postcode
     , c.sic_1
     , s.description sic_code_description
     , s.division sic_code_division
     , s.section sic_code_section
     , ni.insolvency_practitioner_id     
     , i.name practionar_name
     , i.company practitioner_company
     , i.address practitionar_address
     , i.phone   
     , i.email  
  FROM notices n
  LEFT
  JOIN companies c
    ON c.company_number = n.company_number
  LEFT 
  JOIN sic_codes s
    ON s.code = c.sic_1 
  LEFT
  JOIN notice_insolvency_practitioners ni
    ON ni.notice_id = n.id 
 LEFT
  JOIN insolvency_practitioners i
    ON i.id = ni.insolvency_practitioner_id 
 WHERE n.publication_date > '2020-03-01' 
   AND n.publication_date < '2020-03-31'
   AND n.notice_code = 2410
```

The option just disappears and I get this message warning

***Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.***

[image]

And if you click on export without selecting the rows then it will export the table. But I don't want to export one single table. I have created query to select data from 5 tables.

Please guide me how to export query result  into excel /csv file.

Answer (score 1):

The warning explains it all.  None of the columns you are trying to join are  unique which means there is a possible ambiguity in the statement.  i.e.

`JOIN notice_insolvency_practitioners ni
    ON ni.notice_id = n.id`

Because the columns aren't unique, there can be more than one identical value for `n.id` or `ni.notice.id` (or maybe others, it is impossible to tell from here).

Add some unique indexes to your database tables, one on each of the columns you are referencing.